# Nwazet E-Commerce Module for Orchard CMS 1.8, fill data from backend (from database Side)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I need to create one of the E-Commerce site through Orchard-CMS and i am very new to Orchard-CMS. For E-Commerce, I have been using Nwazet Commerce Module of Orchard.

Inside that I have been creating products using nwazet & applied images also using Nwazet Zen gallery and publish it from the orchard Front end at admin side. I have total 13000+ products available with different categories and sub-categories with different types of filters, So how can i merge that database to Nwazet Commerce Database in SQL.

I tried it by adding single product directly from the database side of the nwazet commerce manually but that added detail will not load over the front end & not able to see it. is there any solution for the same to add products directly from the backend and load it over CMS?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are trying to do. Where are your products currently? What exactly did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: Actually I have database available for the products & from that database i need to push all my products related information inside the orchard's database which was abc_Nwazet_Commerce_OrderPartRecord table which was created after installing Nwazet module.

Comment: I think that I need to push all record through store procedure or Sql functions, but before doing such task i simply try to add one manual records directly from the Sql in abc_Nwazet_Commerce_OrderPartRecord table & its related another tables but i'm not able to show that manually added record at the Front-End side of Orchard-CMS.

Comment: Nwazet_Commerce_OrderPartRecord has *nothing* to do with products. As the name should make clear, it deals with orders. When you want to import contents, you best bet is to create a recipe and import that. Start by  creating a product manually, export that, and then use that as a template.

Comment: Hi Bertrand Le Roy !! I have learn about import - export module & already done with the option as you suggested that create template of xml by exporting sample data & follow that xml structure for my data to create another xml with full content which i want to add inside the database. but after creating xml my xml is too much longer, its size is upto 11+ mb. so time out error occurs in orchard & not able to load whole content.

Comment: I have create one sample xml using the particular structure of the exported xml & its working preoprly to importing records inside database because it has very less record of data available in it. but how to handle with too many records of data. it fires the time out request error.

Comment: On the <data> tag you can add a property called BatchSize so for example <data BatchSize="50">...</data>. This will split your import into different transactions

Comment: Or you can create smaller batches and run those one by one.